# How migrate directory ACLs when migrating apache between different VMs?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, amazon-web-services

I am copying two directories from my on-prem server to apache on AWS

`/var/www/my_app`, and `/etc/httpd`

When I get the long listing for `/etc/httpd` I get the following on my local server with all those `+` signs at the end of the permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x+   5 root root  4096 Sep 25 02:53 .
drwxr-xr-x. 111 root root 12288 Dec 10 16:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x+   2 root root  4096 Sep 25 02:53 conf
drwxr-xr-x+   2 root root  4096 Sep 25 02:53 conf.d
drwxrwxr-x+   2 root root  4096 Apr 20  2015 conf_unused.d
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root    19 Sep 25 02:53 logs -> ../../var/log/httpd
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root    29 Sep 25 02:53 modules -> ../../usr/lib64/httpd/modules
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root    19 Sep 25 02:53 run -> ../../var/run/httpd
```

Same is the case for `/var/www/my_app`. I want to understand how can I migrate these groups and their ACLs to my AWS folder?

`getfacl` on `/etc/httpd` or my application's folder produces the output like:

```
# file: var/www/app
# owner: <hidden_username>
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:deptadmins:rwx
group:webadmins:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:deptadmins:rwx
default:group:webadmins:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

I am relatively new to linux admin and want to know how to migrate these ACLs to my AWS server now.

**EDIT**: Perhaps a better question is, do I need all these ACLs for apache to work properly? It's version 2.2 in case anyone's wondering.

Comment: We have no way of knowing if you need those ACLs or not. That is for you to figure out with your coworkers. The web server certainly doesn't need them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rsync --acls` to copy ACLs over to the new destination.

Make sure you’ve got the same user accounts created on both servers.